# Making Qt Creator use MinGW

Tags: qt, mingw, qt-creator

This tutorial [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.4/creator-tool-chains.html) shows how to add toolchains to Qt Creator. I didn't need that, since my installed MinGW automatically shows up there (I checked the path and it's right).

How do I make my project compile with it? I checked the projects tab on the left, and under none of the build configurations do I get the option to use MinGW (only Visual Studio).

Then I went to `Tools->Options->Build and Run->Qt Version`, and tried adding a Qt version for MinGW, but I simply don't have a qmake.exe for MinGW (or do I, and I'm just not aware?).

How can I make Qt Creator use MinGW?

Note: I have the Qt SDK.

Comment: I think i figured it out. I dowloaded QT for MinGW, and added that on QT creator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to add a bit more specific info here. When I originally installed the QtSDK on windows I only had the MVSC option for building. To fix this run the Update QT SDK program and pick the Package Manager option, hit next. Expand "Qt SDK" -> "Development Tools" -> "Desktop QT" -> "Your QT Verision (mine is 4.8.0 (Desktop) at time of writing)" and you should only see a check box next to your Qt version for MSVC. Also check the MinGW option and hit next at the bottom. This will download and install mingw build tool chain for qt creator. You will then have the option to choose MinGW builds instead of MSVC.

Comment: thanks for the detailed instructions, I was baffled by the GUI following (obviously without luck) the path "Help" > "Start Updater" > "Package Manager"+Next > "Qt SDK" > "Miscelaneous" > "MinGW 4.4".

Comment: Thanks, this answer got on the right track. I had to find the C:/Qt/Qt5.20/MaintenanceTool.exe and then patch up the Settings as described in http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/32370/#153719 — then (after looooooong wait "retrieving component information") I could use the Package Manager option to setup.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update Qt, and install mingw support, on windows, you will go to programs and features, find Qt, and right click on it. Click on change, and then hit next until you get to the "Setup - Qt" page. Click on "Add or remove components" then "Next". Wait while it updates "meta information" and then click the arrow next to the version you want to install qt for and check the box for the version of mingw you have (or everything to be safe). Then hit next and then update.
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQOs3.png)